# The best way to create a root filesystem, split between read only and writable

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, read-only, etc, overlayfs

My aim is to create a system where the main parts of the root filesystem are stored on a read-only SD card, with writeable parts located on an SSD set to rw. This is to be done with a view to keeping the root filesystem free from tampering and corruption, and make updating and other maintenance a case of swapping in a pre-configured SD card. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I'm happy with regular partitioning and mounting to take care of /home, /var and the like, but it becomes a lot more tricky when dealing with /etc.
I know some parts of /etc must be writable, such as mtab, and am also aware that /etc is accessed during boot. I have the feeling that it's also advisable to have some parts of /etc persist between boots.

I'm leaning towards using overlayfs, only on /etc, with the upperdir only containing those files which I want to persist. Anything that only needs to be read from /etc will come through from the lowerdir. The upperdir will be writable with new files, though these will only persist through boots, if identified in a whitelist. A script should run on shutdown to copy these files from the upperdir to the whitelist, and the opposite directly after boot (or during if necessary).

### EDIT

The whitelist aims to stop any new files written to the upperdir and persisting between boots. I'll use permissions to manage this too.

**Is this a good way to achieve the result I want, and what are the issues I should be aware of?**

I've read into using mount --bind, but understand that it has issues of it's own, I'm also aware of the method of symlinking /etc/mtab to /proc/mounts/ and am wary of this approach too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've read a lot in the forums and through general web searching, details on implementing overlayfs are very scarce indeed. Please feel free to let me know if I'm greatly over-complicating things, or if there is a better approach.
Also this is my first question so be kind please!!

### EDIT

I've realised I've made a bit of a nebulous, opinion-based type of question, so thought I might re-phrase my question.

**Is there any other useful way setting up this kind of system, other than a union mount?**

Comment: This will be a good read for you: http://www.logicsupply.com/blog/2009/01/27/how-to-build-a-read-only-linux-system/ initramfs is the place to start ;)

Comment: May have a look at UnionFS to mount multiple filesystems overlaid (ro root + rw ssd)... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS

Comment: @Arronical well I would not mess with /etc/ nor with mtab and mount options. Those are proven no to work ... that blog I posted I knew about cuz someone I know used it years ago and it still using that setup. So it will work (though it is difficult and I did not understand large parts of what my friend did at the time).

Comment: Linux is heading to a system where what can be readonly will be.  That is why there is a move towards directories with "/run" (/var/run/). Those will contain the files that need 'write'.

Comment: @Rinzwind: /home also needs to be writable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aufs ( eventually UnionFS) is old and overlayfs in new solution for this in Ubuntu. 
This [script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash#Overlayfs) for overlayfs worked fluently for me with 14.04.1

So you need to copy the script to `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/root-ro`,
then

```
#make the script executable
cmdod 755 /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/root-ro

#add the module overlayfs to initramfs
echo overlayfs >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

#update initramfs
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
```

Reboot to give it a try. Then issue `mount`, you should have output:

> overlayfs-root on / type overlayfs (rw)

You'll find */mnt/root-rw* and */mnt/root-ro* directories for the "lower" and "upper" *layers* of your overlayfs.

You can also add to grub menu ability to load without overlayfs:

```
echo overlayfs >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
cp root-ro /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/root-ro
chmod 755 cp /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/root-ro

#########################GRUB#########################
cat /etc/grub.d/10_linux|sed  s/'linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" simple'/'linux_entry "RW: ${OS}" "${version}" simple'/ |sed  s/'"${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}"'/'"${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} disable-root-ro=true"'/ >/etc/grub.d/11_custom

sed -i.orig -e \
"/{GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY}\" != \"xtrue\" ]; then/s/^.*$/    \
if [ 0 ]; then/" \
/etc/grub.d/11_custom

sed -i.orig -e \
"/in_submenu=:/s/^.*$/    \
/" \
/etc/grub.d/11_custom

sed -i.orig -e \
"/\"Previous Linux versions/s/^.*$/    \
if [ 0 ]; then/" \
/etc/grub.d/11_custom

rm /etc/grub.d/11_custom.orig
#########################GRUB#########################

chmod 777 /etc/grub.d/11_custom
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little further on with implementing this system, and all seems to be going well so far.  Probably means it's about to come crashing down!

Using Overlayfs to create a union filesystem seems to be a workable solution, though I've yet to tackle the issue of scripts starting at boot!  There's plenty of documentation about how to do this part of the process though.

The link posted above by @Rinzwind was a really sensible guide, and is repeated here; http://www.logicsupply.com/blog/2009/01/27/how-to-build-a-read-only-linux-system/